# Finding explicit forms of interations of Mobius transformations

Tags: rational-functions, mobius-transformation

Given the following transformation $R(z)=\frac{3z-2}{2z-1}.$  With the convention that $R^n(z)=R(R(\cdots R(R(z))))$ $n$-times.  I understand by induction, we get that $R^n(z)=\frac{(2n+1)z-2n}{2nz-(2n-1)}=1+\frac{z-1}{2nz-(2n-1)}.$  As $n \to \infty$ we get $R^n(z) \to 1$. So this has a fixed point of $1.$

Consider the following.  If $R$ has a fixed point $\xi$, let $g(z)=\frac{1}{z-\xi}$ and let $S(z)=g(z)R(z)g^{-1}(z)$.  $S$ will fix $z$ provided that $z=\infty$.  Hence $S^n(z)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ and $S^n(z)=g(z)R^n(z)g^{-1}(z).$  $g$ and $S^n(z)$ are explicitly known.

Where I'm stuck is the following.  Consider $R^n(z)=g^{-1}(z)S^n(z)g(z)$.  I'm not sure how to verify the form of $R^n(z)$ by using the facts for $S(z)$ and $g(z)$.  I'm fairly confident that $g(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$.  I'm not sure how to find an $S^n(z)$ such that we will be able to work out $R^n(z)=\frac{(2n+1)z-2n}{2nz-(2n-1)}=1+\frac{z-1}{2nz-(2n-1)}.$

Comment: What is $S(z)$?

Comment: It's a translation.

Comment: Just as I thought, so it's $z\mapsto z+c$. What is $c$?

Comment: $c=1$, so $S^n(z)=z+n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $R^n(z)=g\circ S^n\circ g^{-1}(z)$
(not $g(z)S^n(z)g^{-1}(z)$). As the fixed point of $R$ is $1$, then $g(z)$
must be $1/(z-1)$. We find that if $S(z)=z+1$ then
$$R^n(z)=g^{-1}(S^n(g(z)))=g^{-1}\left(S^n\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)\right)
=g^{-1}\left(\frac1{z-1}+n\right)
=g^{-1}\left(\frac{nz-n+1}{z-1}\right).$$
But $g^{-1}(z)=(1+z)/z$, so
$$R^n(z)=\frac{(n+1)z-n}{nz-n+1}.$$
As this **disagrees** with $R^n$ with $n=1$, then $S$ could not have
been $S(z)=z+1$. I think actually $S(z)=z+2$. Repeating this
calculation with the correct $S(z)$ should give your formula for $R^n(z)$.